# Creating a new image from scratch without any entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a image which just have lot of config files in it. I thought I will create a image from scratch and then will copy all the files to a directory. While starting the container I will use mount to mount a volume and then that volume can be used by all different containers to get the config.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM scratch

ADD configurations /configurations
```

And here is the docker run command

```
docker run --mount source=config,target=/configurations $image
```

When I am trying to start the image I am getting
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: "": executable file not found in $PATH".

Is it possible to have a container wihtout any entrypoint command?

Comment: It's probable better to use directly a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, no.

A container needs either an `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`. It needs *something* to do, otherwise it will exit.

In the case of `scratch`, there is nothing to run, so you would need to add your own binary to the container. A useful guide on doing this can be found here: https://embano1.github.io/post/scratch/.

Otherwise, if size isn't critical, the simplest thing to do is take a small base image, like alpine, and just add a sleep to the end of your Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
ADD yourstuff
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 60; done"]
```

Note that the while loop is used because `alpine` doesn't understand `sleep infinity`

I second the comment, above, though. You would probably be better off mounting a volume containing the configuration files. Doing it this way is somewhat of a hack, and quite an ugly one at that.

Answer (score 0):

A container is a wrapper around a process. When the process exits, the container exits. And when you can't start the process, you can't start the container.

If you want to mount some files into the container, then you just want a directory on the host. Make a named volume and populate it with your files. Then mount that named volume into your containers. Here's a one liner to populate a named volume (called vol_name here) from a local directory (data_dir) in linux (or a bash shell on other platforms):

```
tar -cC data_dir . | docker run -i --rm -v vol_name:/target busybox tar -xC /target
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called a `data only container`
and you can mount `volume from` in your container via dockerfile

but as stated earlier you should just create a local volume with your data in it
and mount that volume in each container that needs access to the files.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/